# How to disable wait for page loading in ProTractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

I try to upload a file in ProTractor to the application, which is developed in Angular with Electron.

To do it manually I need to click on the "Browse" button and then select a file in the windows dialog "Open".

I managed already the part for providing of the path to the file and click on "Open" button on the dialog by using of AutoIt

```
var autoIt = require('autoit');
autoIt.Init();
autoIt.WinActivate("Open");
autoIt.WinWait("Open");
autoIt.ControlSetText("Open", "", "1148", appPath);
autoIt.ControlClick("Open", "", "1");
```

But this part of the code will be not executed after click on the "Browse" button

```
element(by.id('browseText')).click();
```

I guess that ProTractor waits for angular or for page loading, but because after clicking on the button the windows dialog is opened, the execution of further code is blocked. Also afterward I couldn't just output something in the console.

Is there an option to disable wait for page loading and to perform the action immediately after the click?

Unfortunately, the disabling of waiting for Angular didn't help as well as synchronization ignoring

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Thank you in advance for your support.

UPDATED

The problem is in the timing because when I try to execute the small following code

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
element(by.id('browseText')).click()
.then(function () {
    console.log("clicked");
});

browser.sleep(5000)
.then(function () {
    console.log("5 sec are over!");
}); // wait 5 sec

browser.sleep(3000);
console.log("End");
```

The following happens:

1. Firstly the "End" will be added to the console without waiting for 3 seconds.
2. Afterward, the dialog will be opened, that means that the button was clicked
3. And at the end, the test will be failed with Error "function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 90000 milliseconds".

Here is the output of this code:

```
[09:37:14] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:37:14] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

..End
..F

Failures:

1) Scenario: Add an application # features\tst_General.feature:10
   V Before # features\steps\DataGrid.js:20
   V Before # features\steps\General.js:25
   V When The "bounce" application has been added # features\steps\General.js:65

   V After # features\steps\General.js:29
   × After # node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\lib\resultsCapturer.js:2
5
       Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 90000 milli
seconds
           at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\10050296\Documents\workspace\sm-protr
actor-automation\node_modules\cucumber\src\user_code_runner.js:61:18)
           at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
           at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
           at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)

1 scenario (1 failed)
1 step (1 passed)
1m30.217s
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's be clear.
This is work 100%:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Protractor part, as I understand, also work. The `Browser` button is clicked.
So, the issue in the `Autoit` part. The question is - "How to run Autoit?"
Just add `sleep` to check is it `waiting` problem on the `Autoit` side:

```
element(by.id('browseText')).click();
browser.sleep(5000); // wait 5 sec
...
autoit code
...
```

If it works, so the issue in `Autoit` waiting.

Comment: Hi Oleksii, thank you for your answer, but I still have the issue. If I use it in this way as you mentioned then the "Browse" button will be not clicked. It looks like Autoit code is executed before the click on "Browse" button because if during the execution I click on the button manually than the Autoit side will be executed without any problems and afterward the "Browse" button will be clicked once again already from the script. To finalize it looks that both parts work fine to click on the button as well as Autoit code, but there is some synchronization problem.

Comment: that's why you should: 1) Click 2) Wait 3) Run Autoit. Second point can be implemented as I wrote by `browser.sleep(ms)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work or I do something wrong. You can look into the updated part in my question where I implemented click with a wait and afterward log output. And the result is that the `browser.sleep(3000)` will be ignored. And the `console.log("clicked")` will be outputted only once I close windows dialog manually.

Comment: in your updated code I see space after `then`, could you remove it and run again. Also show what you get in a console.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, the result is the same also without space after `then`. I've added the output to my question.